# Xamarin.iOS App crashes immediately while launching for some users

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, sigabrt

I have a problem where the Xamarin.iOS app that has been working fine previously before upgrading to Xamarin.iOS 11.2 from 9.x. The app crashes randomly for majority of users (if not all) upon launching. We are using sqlcipher 4.0.0.1 for encryption. I was able to reproduce it on my iPad Pro and watching the device console log and it appears to be an issue with SQlite but not sure what is causing the crash and how to interpret the log information.

I have tried to symbolicate the crash log, but was able to to it partially which did not help much. But instead the device console log from xcode while the app is crashing provided the below information which made some sense.

> SQLiteException - file is encrypted or is not a database

Can someone please help me with determining what is wrong?

```
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad locationd[61] <Notice>: Client com.dim.pod connected
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad locationd[61] <Notice>: {"msg":"#CLIUA Client CLIUA level changed", "name":"com.dim.pod", "assertedInUseLevel":4}
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad locationd[61] <Notice>: Background indicator enabled for <private> is now <private> (was <private>)
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad locationd[61] <Notice>: {"msg":"kCLConnectionMessageRegistration", "event":"activity", "this":"0x1070aa000", "registrationRequired":0, "registrationReceived":0}
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet(CoreLocation)[486] <Notice>: {"msg":"CLLocationManager", "event":"activity", "_cmd":"setDelegate:", "self":"0x1c401a610", "delegate":"0x1c062be20"}
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet(CoreLocation)[486] <Notice>: {"msg":"CLLocationManager", "event":"activity", "_cmd":"delegate", "self":"0x1c401a610"}
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet(CoreLocation)[486] <Notice>: {"msg":"CLLocationManager", "event":"activity", "_cmd":"delegate", "self":"0x1c401a610"}
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet(CoreLocation)[486] <Notice>: {"msg":"CLLocationManager", "event":"activity", "_cmd":"delegate", "self":"0x1c401a610"}
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad locationd[61] <Notice>: #Warning could not get resource URL for <private>
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad locationd[61] <Notice>: #Warning issue retrieving localized strings for bundle '<private>'
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad locationd[61] <Notice>: #Warning could not get resource URL for <private>
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad locationd[61] <Notice>: #Warning issue retrieving localized strings for bundle '<private>'
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad locationd[61] <Notice>: com.dim.pod is creating a CLLocationManager, but does not have any NSLocation*UsageDescription keys
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad locationd[61] <Notice>: {"msg":"update client authorization mask", "name":"com.dim.pod", "old":0, "new":0, "localAuthorizationChange":1}
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad locationd[61] <Notice>: {"msg":"kCLConnectionMessagePausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically", "event":"activity", "this":"0x1070aa000", "registrationRequired":1, "registrationReceived":1}
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad atc(AirTrafficDevice)[36] <Notice>: <ATLegacyMessageLink: 0x103294a40, wifi=0> ---> [Ping Request. id=976, Session=0, params=(null)]
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: Unhandled managed exception:
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Shared.ViewModels.IMainViewModel", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: Calling constructor Shared.Repo.BaseRepo`1[[Shared.Common.Branding, Shared.Common, Version=1.0.6544.29725, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]](Shared.Common.ISecureDatabase database, GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.IMessenger messenger).
Exception is: SQLiteException - file is encrypted or is not a database
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving Shared.ViewModels.MainViewModel,(none) (mapped from Shared.ViewModels.IMainViewModel, (none))
  Resolving parameter "settingsService" of constructor Shared.ViewModels.MainViewModel(Shared.Services.ILifecycleService lifecycleService, Shared.Services.ISettingsService settingsService, Shared.Services.ISyncService syncService, Shared.Common.ITimerService timerService, Shared.Common.IDispatcherService dispatcherService, Shared.Common.IExten<\M-b\M^@\M-&>
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical: Stacktrace:
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical: 
Native stacktrace:
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     0   iOSTablet                           0x00000001042d76a4 sqlite3_sleep + 31848372
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00000001871c7b44 _sigtramp + 52
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     2   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001871cd354 <redacted> + 396
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x0000000187028fd8 abort + 140
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     4   iOSTablet                           0x000000010440fea8 xamarin_get_block_descriptor + 4592
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     5   iOSTablet                           0x000000010431e338 sqlite3_sleep + 32138312
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     6   iOSTablet                           0x00000001042d71e4 sqlite3_sleep + 31847156
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     7   iOSTablet                           0x00000001042d6224 sqlite3_sleep + 31843124
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet(CFNetwork)[486] <Notice>: Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     8   iOSTablet                           0x00000001042ce1d0 sqlite3_sleep + 31810272
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet(CFNetwork)[486] <Notice>: Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     9   iOSTablet                           0x0000000102865b88 sqlite3_sleep + 4119704
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet(CFNetwork)[486] <Notice>: Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     10  iOSTablet                           0x00000001025811a8 sqlite3_sleep + 1086136
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     11  iOSTablet                           0x0000000102836644 sqlite3_sleep + 3925844
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     12  iOSTablet                           0x00000001042e6790 sqlite3_sleep + 31910048
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     13  iOSTablet                           0x000000010435fe44 sqlite3_sleep + 32407380
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     14  iOSTablet                           0x0000000104362fa4 sqlite3_sleep + 32420020
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     15  iOSTablet                           0x00000001042ca9f4 sqlite3_sleep + 31795972
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     16  iOSTablet                           0x0000000104414c68 xamarin_localized_string_format_9 + 3232
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     17  iOSTablet                           0x0000000102580d48 sqlite3_sleep + 1085016
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical:     18  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000186f8a56c <redacted> + 4
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet[486] <Notice>: critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet(CFNetwork)[486] <Notice>: TIC Enabling TLS [1:0x1c016cc00]
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet(CFNetwork)[486] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Start [1:0x1c016cc00]
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad iOSTablet(CFNetwork)[486] <Notice>: Task <BB4F1538-1269-4E0D-8DD3-FB5E8A833C16>.<1> setting up Connection 1
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad assertiond[64] <Notice>: Client relinquished <BKProcessAssertion: 0x100c36010; "Deliver Message" (suspend:10s); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&8D53F0618A2C>
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad assertiond[64] <Notice>: [iOSTablet:486] Deactivate assertion: <BKProcessAssertion: 0x100c36010; "Deliver Message" (suspend:10s); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&8D53F0618A2C>
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad assertiond[64] <Notice>: [iOSTablet:486] dump all assertions HWM:3 (deactivateAssertion): {
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x100c18a80; "Resume" (activation:inf); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&3A0E463B0920> [active]
}
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad assertiond[64] <Notice>: [iOSTablet:486] Setting jetsam priority to 10 [0x10100]
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad assertiond[64] <Notice>: [iOSTablet:486] dump all assertions HWM:3 (CPUMON check): {
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x100c18a80; "Resume" (activation:inf); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&3A0E463B0920> [active]
}
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad assertiond[64] <Notice>: [iOSTablet:486] Remove assertion: <BKProcessAssertion: 0x100c36010; "Deliver Message" (suspend:10s); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&8D53F0618A2C>
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad assertiond[64] <Notice>: [iOSTablet:486] dump all assertions HWM:3 (CPUMON check): {
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x100c18a80; "Resume" (activation:inf); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&3A0E463B0920> [active]
}
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad assertiond[64] <Notice>: -[BKAssertion dealloc] - <0x100c36010>
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad SpringBoard(KeyboardArbiter)[53] <Error>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad locationd[61] <Notice>: #Warning Location connection invalid!
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad locationd[61] <Notice>: {"msg":"CLConnection::handleDisconnection", "event":"activity"}
Jan  3 10:51:43 TMs-iPad locationd[61] <Notice>: Client com.dim.pod disconnected
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the API that is computing the SQL lite file location is wrong so you are passing the wrong filename to it.